# sites method styling code problem

Tags: support

One of the site returned from the sites method has the following styling codes

```
"site_type": "main_site",
  "name": "GIS",
  "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/gis/img/logo-small.png",
  "api_site_parameter": "gis",
  "site_url": "http://gis.stackexchange.com",
  "audience": "cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals",
  "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/gis/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
  "site_state": "normal",
  "styling": {
    "link_color": "#0077CC",
    "tag_foreground_color": "#e0e0e0",
    "tag_background_color": "#f5f5f5"
  }
```

The foreground color and background color are actually shades of grey which makes the text not readable.

Also would it be possible for the color codes to always return the 6 digit code rather than #fff for some and #ffffff for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some bad colors got set for GIS, I've corrected them.

Both three and six digit versions of colors can be returned by the API, it's been this way since V1.0.  I have, however, added a note about that on the documentation as it's non-obvious.

Comment: Awesome...GIS color combo looks good now. Just wanted the color to be uniform, since android color parser wont accept 3 digit. So had to do a manually conversion from 3 to 6.